# Reading names of multiple .txt files from a folder in python

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to read the names of multiple .txt files from a single folder? I right now am only able to read the contents of the files.

```
import glob
import errno
path = 'C:/Users/rabhi/Desktop/NLP/aclImdb/test/neg/*.txt'
files = glob.glob(path)
for name in files:
    try:
        with open(name) as f:
            for line in f:
                print(line.split())
    except IOError as exc: 
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
            raise
```

Comment: There are many ways to go about this. Could you describe your specific use and where you are having any issues?

Comment: The file names are numerically named. For ex: "4_6" means that the fourth file has a rating of 6. The text inside the file is a review for a movie. So I would need both the text portion of the review with the rating awarded to it. This is for a Sentiment Analysis project

Comment: What issue are you having though? In your post you say you are able to read the contents of the file. If you need to grab the rating from the filename, you can use `split` to separate the number and rating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) for this:

```
import os
def main():
    for dirName, subDirList, fileList in os.walk('path'):
        for subDir in subDirList:
            for file in fileList:
                #Do something with file
main()
```

This recursively goes through your files in a given directory.
To ignore sub-directories you can try something like this:

```
import os
def main():
    for dirName, subDirList, fileList in os.walk('path'):
        for file in fileList:
            #Do something with file
main()
```